# Char string array in a struct, value won't change according to main (in C)?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, struct

So I'm writing a sort of command line interpreter in C, I feel like there's too much going on to just paste all the code here.

But basically I have a struct that stores data for one "command line". It has some ints, some char arrays, and it has an array of char pointers (to be used as arguments for execvp later).

In main I call a parse() function that reads a line, and changes the struct for that line. It uses a separate function I wrote called getword() that takes a char* and fills it with a word from input. If I change an int or a char array in parse(), it's reflected in main. The problem is when I try to store a string into my args array, I think it's pointing towards an element that main doesn't understand (storage).

This works perfectly fine if I simply swap storage for something like "hello world". Is there a simple way to ensure main can read this value?

Here's a summarized version:

```
char storage[MAXCHARS];

struct cmd{
   char *args[MAXITEM];
   char lastWord[MAXCHARS];

   int numArgs; //there are more but not necessary
};

struct cmd cmds[10];

void parse(){
   getword(storage);
   cmds[0].args[0] = storage;
   printf("%s\n",cmds[0].args[0]); //prints correctly
}

int main(){
    parse();
    printf("%s\n",cmds[0].args[0]); //prints null
}
```

I'm happy to elaborate on anything, I just felt it would be too much if I threw everything here.

Comment: You are right not to put all your original code in. But you need to construct complete code which can reproduce the problem. For example, we don't know what `MAXCHARS` is and we don't know what `getword` does - the function could be overflowing the buffer for all we know. Or `getword` could be writing a non NUL-terminated char sequence. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: This will happen if you write something to `storage` having a size greater than `MAXCHARS`